# odata error - operator with incompatible types was detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, binary-operators

I'm new to odata and WebApi.
I'm trying to send the following odata query: ?$filter=ExternalIds eq '5'

ExternalIds is part of an object and define as:

```
    public Id ExternalIds { get; set; }
```

`public class Id
{
[DataMember]
public string Name { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string Value { get; set; }
}`

i'm getting the error:
"A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'GenericAPIInterface.Entities.User.Id' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the property values on a related class you will need to use the navigation syntax within `$filter`, e.g. `...?$filter=ExternalIds/Value eq '5'`. Also, if `ExternalIds` is an entity (has it's own id), you may want to expand it using `$expand`. This is not strictly necessary for the filter clause to work, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had the same problem - turned out that I used a query *Id eq "5"* while it should have been *Id eq 5* so unquoting basically helped.